# How do I separate my email and my husbands emails from a shared iCloud account?

Tags: icloud, email

Back in 2007 when we first started an iCloud account, my husband and I used the same one.  As a result, our emails all come into the same INBOX, but we each have our own email address with a mac.com ending.
I want to move my email address to be under my new apple ID.  Can I do this?